# Ajax loaded content doesn't inherit CSS

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to load a form with jQuery Ajax, however when I do, the CSS of the page is not being applied to the form so it looked all messed up. The rest of the CSS on the page works and stays the same, but the new elements being added to the DOM from my Ajax call don't seem to inherit the CSS.

Here is my code:

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Registration.php",
  data: "action=DRAWFORM",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(html) {
   $("#content").append(html);
  }
 });
```

HTML

```
<div id="registration-container">
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">

<p><label for="teamname">Team Name</label><input type="text" id="teamname" name="teamname"/></p>
<p><label for="contactnumber">Contact #</label><input type="text" id="contactnumber" name="contactnumber"/></p>

<div id="teaminfo-headers">
<span class="ID">ID</span>
<span class="name">Name</span>
<span class="UCINetID">UCINetID</span>
</div>
<div id="teaminfo">
<span><input type="text" id="memberID0" name="memberID0" class="text-ID" /></span>
<span><input type="text" id="memberName0" name="memberName0" class="text-name"/></span>
<span><input type="text" id="memberUCIID0" name="memberUCIID0" class="text-UCIID" /></span>
<br />
<span><input type="text" id="memberID1" name="memberID1" class="text-ID" /></span>
<span><input type="text" id="memberName1" name="memberName1" class="text-name" /></span>
<span><input type="text" id="memberUCIID1" name="memberUCIID1" class="text-UCIID" /></span>
<br />
</div>
<a onClick="addMember();return false;" href="#" >Add Member...</a>

<div id="software">
<fieldset><legend>Which software will you use?</legend>
          <label for="software_checkbox_0" class="labelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="software_checkbox" id="software_checkbox_0" class="inputCheckbox" value="Final Cut" /> Final Cut</label>
          <label for="software_checkbox_1" class="labelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="software_checkbox" id="software_checkbox_1" class="inputCheckbox" value="iMovie" /> iMovie</label>
          <label for="software_checkbox_2" class="labelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="software_checkbox" id="software_checkbox_2" class="inputCheckbox" value="Premiere)" /> Premiere</label>
          <label for="software_checkbox_3" class="labelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="software_checkbox" id="software_checkbox_3" class="inputCheckbox" value="Movie Maker" /> Movie Maker</label>
</fieldset>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#registration-container {
    width: 620px;
}

div#teaminfo-headers span.ID {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

div#teaminfo-headers span.name {
    margin-left: 75px;
    margin-right: 75px;
}

div#teaminfo-headers span.UCINetID {
    margin-left: 75px;
    margin-right: 75px;
}

form p {
    text-align:center;
}

form p label {
    width: 100px;
}

form input.text-ID {
    width: 100px;
}

form input.text-name {
    width: 200px;
}

form input.text-UCIID {
    width: 200px;
}

form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  min-width: 560px;
  max-width: 620px;
  width: 590px;
}

label {
  font-size: 100%;
}

form div fieldset {
  clear: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  margin: 0 0 0 144px;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}

form div fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form div label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

form div label.labelCheckbox {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px 142px;
  text-align: left;
}

form div fieldset label.labelCheckbox {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 170px;
}

form div input.inputCheckbox, form div input.inputRadio, input.inputCheckbox, input.inputRadio {
  display: inline;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 140px;
}

form input {
    margin: 2 0 0 5;
    padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

form div label.labelCheckbox {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 4px 0 0 18px;
  text-indent: -18px;
  line-height: 120%;
}

form div label.labelCheckbox input.inputCheckbox, form div label.labelRadio input.inputRadio, label.labelCheckbox input.inputCheckbox, label.labelRadio input.inputRadio {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Any help or further insight as to what might be the problem would be greatly appreciated. If it's any help, I am testing it in Chrome.

Thank you.

EDIT: Added CSS

Comment: Only in Chrome? Have you tried other browsers?